# Materialize material_select() not working before refresh in Meteor app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, materialize

I'm using following select in a template in my Meteor project

```
    <div class="input-field">
        <select name="color" id="color">
            <option value="%23B1365F">Pink</option>
            <option value="%232952A3">Blue</option>
            <option value="%23711616">Red</option>
            <option value="%2328754E">Green</option>
            <option value="%23BE6D00">Orange</option>
            <option value="%23113F47">Sea Blue</option>
            <option value="%235229A3">Purple</option>
            <option value="%23528800">Olive</option>
            <option value="%2388880E">Gold</option>
            <option value="%23333333">Black</option>
        </select>
        <label for="color">Colour: </label>
    </div>
```

With the following in my js-file to initialize the Materialize select dropdown

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Template.layout_settings.onRendered(function () {
        $('select').material_select();
      });
    }
```

However, the select dialog only works/shows after a refresh, before a refresh I get following error in console:

```
    TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function
      at null.<anonymous> (settings.js:48)
      at template.js:116
      at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:457)
      at fireCallbacks (template.js:112)
      at null.<anonymous> (template.js:205)
      at view.js:107
      at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
      at view.js:106
      at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:497)
      at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
```

After a refresh it works perfectly fine, does anyone has any idea why this happens?
Couldn't find anything on google.

[Before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEFym.jpg)

[After refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgrea.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you add materialize?

Comment: @Stephen Woods Meteor add materialize:materialize in cmd in root folder of the project

Comment: What is output if you do `console.log($('select'));` before the `material_select()` line?  Also, what version of materialize is showing up when you do `meteor list`?  It looks like this was a known issue last year: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1946

Comment: @StephenWoods the output I get is: [this](http://imgur.com/8D19v2a), I'm using materialize version 0.97.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the prettiest of workarounds, but it fixed the problem.

Materialze doesn't seem to add its jQuery functions in time to use them in the onRendered function of a Blaze template.

It does however add the function to the `Package.jquery.$.fn.material_select` object.

I just created my own jQuery function which referenced the function body of that object:

```
    (function($){
        $.fn.material_select_fix = Package.jquery.$.fn.material_select;
    })(jQuery)
    $("select").material_select_fix();
```

I hope this works for other cases too...

Comment: Currently it's not working for me. Do you have any idea why it's not working? Where should I put this code? In client-side `Meteor.startup`? or part?